# Everything in www folder is removing & getting back to initial while adding plugins in cordova from cmd

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Sometimes when I add plugins from command prompt to existing project, every file from www gets removed & www gets back to initial like a new cordova project `www` folder. How can I get the backup? What can I do so that this will not happen? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to code in WWW which is inside your base directory . Not inside the www directory which is inside **\platforms\android** or **\platforms\ios**
 directory. because when you hit android build It take www base directory and push it inside plateform project

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll try this.

Comment: Placing code in www in base directory does not work. The project shows blank screen on run.