# When I add new plugin through CLI in my cordova app, the www folder removes my files?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, cordova-cli

Whenever I add new plugin to my cordova app, all my files in the www folder are gone and the default phonegap project files(Device is ready!) gets back.

So whenever I have to add new plugin, I have to back up my www folder and then add plugin, then paste back my code.

I install through Cordova CLI. Cordova version is 6.1.1.

I put all my files in project/platforms/ios/www.

I tried putting my files in www in the base directory as per mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677271/everything-in-www-folder-is-removing-getting-back-to-initial-while-adding-plug) but it does not work. Screen is white blank on running the app.

So please suggest a solution so that when I add plugin, all my files in www folder stays. Thanks.

Comment: don't put your whole source in the www folder. structure your solution differently. have a separate source folder on the same level or above the cordova app, and have the www folder populated during your build phase. the have the www folder only contain the final version of your app. thus post plugin update you can just rebuild, and continue with life as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting your files in the wrong place.  The entire platforms folder should be considered a build artifact and not used in this way, nor should it be committed to source control.

In the "root" of your Cordova project (the folder that config.xml lives in), there's a www folder.  You should keep your application files there.  When you run:

```
cordova build ios
```

All files and folders inside www will be copied to:

```
platforms/ios/www
```

And replace any that were there before.  When you run:

```
cordova build ios
```

All files and folders inside www will be copied to:

```
platforms/android/assets/www
```

See the [Cordova CLI documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Ok. I will put my code in www(in base directory). I will keep coding from that folder. Now whenever I need to run my app(for testing), I will have to build the app from CLI and then run it from IDE?

Comment: You don't need the IDE you can use cordova build <platform name> to build then cordova emulate <platform name> to run in the emulator.